# When to use inox (stainless steel) screws in an anchor as opposed to using galvanized/normal screw?

Tags: screws, mounting, anchor

Is it only when there is a possibility of humidity? Are [inox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stainless_steel) screws better for withstanding some weights, are they tougher or just their water handling is better? I see there are different types of Inox too, like A2, A4, supposedly better for handling water.

I am assuming that for home use and weight holding, it might not matter, but what I am asking is in theory; which screw would handle weight better, and if I compare inox to other normal screws, what should I go for and why?

Also is A4 Inox worth the price?

Answer (score 1):

Inox is stainless steel with 10% (or more) chromium. The different grades have different alloys and create a stronger fastener. In industrial settings we do use A4 because it is superior. Think of case hardened for a parallel most think of in the U.S. do you really need the best grade? That depends on what you are doing high heat or cryogenic freezers may require a high grade but for home use I probably would not pay the extra. In fact depending on the type of fasteners needed you may have cheaper options with coated screws 1/10 the cost with 20+ year wearability. Although inox is stainless it can have iron oxide rust spots and if metal dust gets on the fastener in a damp area it can affect the material and can end up looking like a shiny rusted fastener. The difference I see with inox and galvinization both hot dipped and electroplated is after torquing a fastener in the contact point on galvanized parts may start rusting where with inox won't. It would help to know if you are talking about machine screws or wood screws to provide better comparisons.

Comment: I am talking about screws that will be screwed in a plastic wall anchor, which means wood screws (I think wood screws are the only recommended in such case).

Comment: Your mileage will vary with product, but I've found many stainless screws to be brittle (prone to breaking in use, though it's unlikely you'd break anything in a wall anchor). For humidity, I'll grab painted deck screws.

Comment: For a specific grade of stainless I would suggest if it is made out of 303 the screw would not rust and 303 is soft compared to other alloys I doubt you would ever break one in plastic anchors. I have several dive knives made out of 303 and they are guaranteed for life not to rust or break but they do bend and don't hold a sharp edge. That's why I think it would be a good alloy based on your needs.